# stack overflow exception upon using a setter through another class

Tags: java, android, stack-overflow

The program runs if i comment everything to do with the other activity out, but when I try to run my program with it in it crashes as soon as it hits this line:

```
    if(savedInstanceState == null)
    {
        settings.setImperial(true);
        settings.setUK(true);
    }
```

I have created an Object of the class I wish to use:

```
private FuelEconomySettingsActivity settings = new FuelEconomySettingsActivity();
```

Here is **FuelEconomyCalculatorActivity.java**

```
package com.example.fuelcalculator;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FuelEconomyCalculatorActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        OnClickListener {

    private EditText fuelEditText;
    private EditText distanceEditText;
    private TextView mpgTextView;
    private TextView litresTextView;
    private Button calculateButton;
    private Button clearButton;
    private RadioButton gallonsRadio;
    private RadioButton litresRadio;
    private RadioButton milesRadio;
    private RadioButton kmRadio;
    private String mpg = " ";
    private String kp100 = " ";

    private FuelEconomySettingsActivity settings = new FuelEconomySettingsActivity();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fuel_economy_calculator);
        fuelEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fuelEditText);
        distanceEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.distanceEditText);
        mpgTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mpgTextView);
        litresTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.litresTextView);
        calculateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculateButton);
        clearButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clearButton);
        gallonsRadio = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.gallonsRadio);
        litresRadio = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.litresRadio);
        milesRadio = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.milesRadio);
        kmRadio = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.kmRadio);
        calculateButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        clearButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        litresRadio.setChecked(true);
        kmRadio.setChecked(true);

        if(savedInstanceState == null)
        {
            settings.setImperial(true);
            settings.setUK(true);
        }

        if (settings.getImperial()) {
            litresRadio.setChecked(true);
            kmRadio.setChecked(true);
        } else if (settings.getMetric()) {
            gallonsRadio.setChecked(true);
            milesRadio.setChecked(true);
        }

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mpg = savedInstanceState.getString("mpg");
            kp100 = savedInstanceState.getString("kp100");
        }
        initializeViews();
    }

    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        savedInstanceState.putString("mpg", (String) mpgTextView.getText());
        savedInstanceState.putString("kp100", (String) litresTextView.getText());
    }

    private void initializeViews() {
        mpgTextView.setText(mpg);
        litresTextView.setText(kp100);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.fuel_economy_calculator, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings: {
            Intent intent = new Intent(FuelEconomyCalculatorActivity.this,
                    FuelEconomySettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

        case R.id.action_about: {
            Intent intent = new Intent(FuelEconomyCalculatorActivity.this,
                    FuelEconomyAboutPageActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.calculateButton) {
            float mpg = 0;
            float kmLitres = 0;
            // it doesn't matter which you use here, as long
            // as you use a fuel and a distance method
            if (settings.getUK() && !settings.getUS()) {
                if (getKM() > 0 && getLitres() > 0) {
                    mpg = getMiles() / getGallons();
                    kmLitres = getLitres() / (getKM() / 100);
                    mpgTextView.setText(String.format("%.2f", mpg));
                    litresTextView.setText(String.format("%.2f", kmLitres));
                }
            } else if (settings.getUS() && !settings.getUK()) {
                if (getKM() > 0 && getLitres() > 0) {
                    mpg = getMiles() / getGallonsUS();
                    kmLitres = getLitresUS() / (getKM() / 100);
                    mpgTextView.setText(String.format("%.2f", mpg));
                    litresTextView.setText(String.format("%.2f", kmLitres));
                }
            }
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.clearButton) {
            resetValues();
        }

    }

    public float CheckValues(EditText input) {
        float value = 0;
        try {
            value = Float.parseFloat(input.getText().toString());
            if (value < 1) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this,
                        "Please enter a number that is larger than 0",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a number",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
        return value;
    }

    public void resetValues() {
        mpg = " ";
        kp100 = " ";
        fuelEditText.setText("");
        distanceEditText.setText("");
        mpgTextView.setText("");
        litresTextView.setText("");
    }

    public float getKM() {
        float distance = CheckValues(distanceEditText);
        if (milesRadio.isChecked()) {
            distance = (float) (distance * 1.60934);
        }
        return distance;
    }

    public float getMiles() {
        float distance = CheckValues(distanceEditText);
        if (kmRadio.isChecked()) {
            distance = (float) (distance * 0.62137);
        }
        return distance;
    }

    public float getLitres() {
        float fuel = CheckValues(fuelEditText);
        if (gallonsRadio.isChecked()) {
            fuel = (float) (fuel * 4.54609);
        }
        return fuel;
    }

    public float getLitresUS() {
        float fuel = CheckValues(fuelEditText);
        if (gallonsRadio.isChecked()) {
            fuel = (float) (fuel * 3.785411784);
        }
        return fuel;
    }

    public float getGallons() {
        float fuel = CheckValues(fuelEditText);
        if (litresRadio.isChecked()) {
            fuel = (float) (fuel * 0.219969);
        }
        return fuel;
    }

    public float getGallonsUS() {
        float fuel = CheckValues(fuelEditText);
        if (litresRadio.isChecked()) {
            fuel = (float) (fuel * 0.264172);
        }
        return fuel;
    }
}
```

And here is my **FuelEconomySettingsActivity.java**

```
package com.example.fuelcalculator;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.RadioButton;

public class FuelEconomySettingsActivity extends FuelEconomyCalculatorActivity {

    private RadioButton metricRadio;
    private RadioButton imperialRadio;
    private RadioButton usRadio;
    private RadioButton ukRadio;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fuel_economy_about);

        metricRadio = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.metricRadioText);
        imperialRadio = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.imperialRadioText);
        usRadio = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.usRadioText);
        ukRadio = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.ukRadioText);

        imperialRadio.setChecked(true);
        ukRadio.setChecked(true);

    }

    public void setMetric(boolean b) {
        metricRadio.setChecked(b);
    }

    public void setImperial(boolean b) {
        imperialRadio.setChecked(b);
    }

    public void setUS(boolean b) {
        usRadio.setChecked(b);
    }

    public void setUK(boolean b) {
        ukRadio.setChecked(b);
    }   

    public boolean getMetric() {
        if (metricRadio.isChecked())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public boolean getImperial() {
        if (imperialRadio.isChecked())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public boolean getUS() {
        if (usRadio.isChecked())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public boolean getUK() {
        if (ukRadio.isChecked())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.fuel_economy_calculator, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_about: {
            Intent intent = new Intent(FuelEconomySettingsActivity.this,
                    FuelEconomyAboutPageActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

        case R.id.action_main: {
            Intent intent = new Intent(FuelEconomySettingsActivity.this,
                    FuelEconomyCalculatorActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the logcat

```
07-17 16:04:44.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31697): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-17 16:04:44.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31697): Process: com.example.fuelcalculator, PID: 31697
07-17 16:04:44.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31697): java.lang.StackOverflowError
07-17 16:04:44.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31697):    at java.lang.ref.FinalizerReference.add(FinalizerReference.java:54)
07-17 16:04:44.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31697):    at android.os.StrictMode$InstanceTracker.<init>(StrictMode.java:2255)
07-17 16:04:44.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31697):    at android.os.StrictMode.trackActivity(StrictMode.java:1957)
07-17 16:04:44.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31697):    at android.app.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:779)
07-17 16:04:44.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31697):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.<init>(FragmentActivity.java:76)
07-17 16:04:44.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31697):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.<init>(ActionBarActivity.java:55)
07-17 16:04:44.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31697):    at com.example.fuelcalculator.FuelEconomyCalculatorActivity.<init>(FuelEconomyCalculatorActivity.java:16)
07-17 16:04:44.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31697):    at com.example.fuelcalculator.FuelEconomySettingsActivity.<init>(FuelEconomySettingsActivity.java:9)
07-17 16:04:44.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31697):    at com.example.fuelcalculator.FuelEconomyCalculatorActivity.<init>(FuelEconomyCalculatorActivity.java:32)
07-17 16:04:44.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31697):    at com.example.fuelcalculator.FuelEconomySettingsActivity.<init>(FuelEconomySettingsActivity.java:9)
07-17 16:04:44.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31697):    at com.example.fuelcalculator.FuelEconomyCalculatorActivity.<init>(FuelEconomyCalculatorActivity.java:32)
07-17 16:04:44.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31697):    at com.example.fuelcalculator.FuelEconomySettingsActivity.<init>(FuelEconomySettingsActivity.java:9)
07-17 16:04:44.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31697):    at com.example.fuelcalculator.FuelEconomyCalculatorActivity.<init>(FuelEconomyCalculatorActivity.java:32)
07-17 16:04:44.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31697):    at com.example.fuelcalculator.FuelEconomySettingsActivity.<init>(FuelEconomySettingsActivity.java:9)
07-17 16:04:44.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31697):    at com.example.fuelcalculator.FuelEconomyCalculatorActivity.<init>(FuelEconomyCalculatorActivity.java:32)
07-17 16:04:44.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31697):    at com.example.fuelcalculator.FuelEconomySettingsActivity.<init>(FuelEconomySettingsActivity.java:9)
07-17 16:04:44.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31697):    at com.example.fuelcalculator.FuelEconomyCalculatorActivity.<init>(FuelEconomyCalculatorActivity.java:32)
07-17 16:04:44.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31697):    at com.example.fuelcalculator.FuelEconomySettingsActivity.<init>(FuelEconomySettingsActivity.java:9)
07-17 16:04:44.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31697):    at com.example.fuelcalculator.FuelEconomyCalculatorActivity.<init>(FuelEconomyCalculatorActivity.java:32)
07-17 16:04:44.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31697):    at com.example.fuelcalculator.FuelEconomySettingsActivity.<init>(FuelEconomySettingsActivity.java:9)
07-17 16:04:44.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31697):    at com.example.fuelcalculator.FuelEconomyCalculatorActivity.<init>(FuelEconomyCalculatorActivity.java:32)
07-17 16:04:44.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31697):    at com.example.fuelcalculator.FuelEconomySettingsActivity.<init>(FuelEconomySettingsActivity.java:9)
07-17 16:04:44.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31697):    at com.example.fuelcalculator.FuelEconomyCalculatorActivity.<init>(FuelEconomyCalculatorActivity.java:32)
07-17 16:04:44.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31697):    at com.example.fuelcalculator.FuelEconomySettingsActivity.<init>(FuelEconomySettingsActivity.java:9)
07-17 16:04:44.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31697):    at com.example.fuelcalculator.FuelEconomyCalculatorActivity.<init>(FuelEconomyCalculatorActivity.java:32)
07-17 16:04:44.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31697):    at com.example.fuelcalculator.FuelEconomySettingsActivity.<init>(FuelEconomySettingsActivity.java:9)
07-17 16:04:44.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31697):    at com.example.fuelcalculator.FuelEconomyCalculatorActivity.<init>(FuelEconomyCalculatorActivity.java:32)
07-17 16:04:44.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31697):    at com.example.fuelcalculator.FuelEconomySettingsActivity.<init>(FuelEconomySettingsActivity.java:9)
07-17 16:04:44.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31697):    at com.example.fuelcalculator.FuelEconomyCalculatorActivity.<init>(FuelEconomyCalculatorActivity.java:32)
07-17 16:04:44.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31697):    at com.example.fuelcalculator.FuelEconomySettingsActivity.<init>(FuelEconomySettingsActivity.java:9)
07-17 16:04:44.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31697):    at com.example.fuelcalculator.FuelEconomyCalculatorActivity.<init>(FuelEconomyCalculatorActivity.java:32)
07-17 16:04:44.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31697):    at com.example.fuelcalculator.FuelEconomySettingsActivity.<init>(FuelEconomySettingsActivity.java:9)
07-17 16:04:44.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31697):    at com.example.fuelcalculator.FuelEconomyCalculatorActivity.<init>(FuelEconomyCalculatorActivity.java:32)
07-17 16:04:44.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31697):    at com.example.fuelcalculator.FuelEconomySettingsActivity.<init>(FuelEconomySettingsActivity.java:9)
07-17 16:04:44.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31697):    at com.example.fuelcalculator.FuelEconomyCalculatorActivity.<init>(FuelEconomyCalculatorActivity.java:32)
07-17 16:04:44.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31697):    at com.example.fuelcalculator.FuelEconomySettingsActivity.<init>(FuelEconomySettingsActivity.java:9)
07-17 16:04:44.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31697):    at com.example.fuelcalculator.FuelEconomyCalculatorActivity.<init>(FuelEconomyCalculatorActivity.java:32)
07-17 16:04:44.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31697):    at com.example.fuelcalculator.FuelEconomySettingsActivity.<init>(FuelEconomySettingsActivity.java:9)
07-17 16:04:44.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31697):    at com.example.fuelcalculator.FuelEconomyCalculatorActivity.<init>(FuelEconomyCalculatorActivity.java:32)
07-17 16:04:44.868: E/AndroidRuntime(31697):    at com.example.fuelcalculator.FuelEconomySettingsActivity.<init>(FuelEconomySettingsActivity.java:9
```

I am new to Android so I am not very good at debugging so could someone please assist me with my predicament?

Comment: You're programatically creating a new activity?  That alone is really really wrong, its something you should never do.  You need to rethink your entire approach here.

Comment: Do you mean this line? `private FuelEconomySettingsActivity settings = new FuelEconomySettingsActivity();`?

Comment: logcat or it didn't happen.

Comment: How else could I access the methods of the FuelEconomySettingsActivity

Comment: Yes. that is wrong and will not work as well. activity classes are not supposed to have getters or setters because they can not be instantiated.

Comment: well, I guess it is time to rethink this settings thing

Comment: Typically you either hold settings in a singleton class or a shared preference, depending on if you want them to be sticky between runs of the application or not.  In addition, using shared preferences lets you use PreferenceActivity which will do most of the work of a settings screen for you

Comment: Thank you, not knowing Android that well, I did not know where to go since the posting of this. You have solved the question Gabe

Comment: you cannot create an activity. it will not be properly initialized and will not be useable at all.

Comment: @njzk2 Gabe has already solved the issue, Thanks for your input though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beside the fact that instantiating an activity is something you cannot really do in android (which @Gabe answered),

The fundamental Java reason of your issue is that you have a class `Calculator` and a class `Settings extends Calculator`, and you create a new `Settings` in the init of `Calculator`.

When you create a new `Calculator` activity, a new `Settings` activity is created. This class extends `Calculator`, and therefore inherits the init and the fields.

Therefore, creating a new `Settings` calls the init for `Calculator`, which creates itself a new `Settings`, and so on.

This is what causes the stack overflow.